# How to check for sqlite date falls within a specif range?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have to check for a date which falls between two dates (we already saved the start and end dates to the db). So I come up with,

```
SELECT CONTACTNAME
FROM SHIPMENT 
WHERE date('11-15-2010') 
BETWEEN start_date
AND end_date;
```

Is this the correct way to go?

Comment: Store your dates as `2010-11-15` and then it should not even matter if they are treated as dates or strings, because even lexigraphic comparison should behave correctly.

Comment: Ya. I stored dates in the above format. Does this query works? Let me check it once I get into the office.

Comment: Thanks guys, I managed to solve this problem on python by running,

`d = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mcnames m where m.name REGEXP ? and date('{}') BETWEEN m.start_date AND m.end_date".format('1971-01-21'), [r'(?i)\b' + part + r'\b'])`